# Oracle text curly braces behavior

Tags: oracle, search, nlp, oracle-text

I'm using oracle text to do a readahead (according to the spec writer) in the search bar.

Basically, a user can start typing text and we fill the suggestions bar with likely matches.

I tried using oracle text for this, and ran into some issues, and the latest one being:

Table contains this entry for answertext: ... we offer many pricing options ...

```
SELECT
    questiontext as qtext,
   answertext as text,
   questionid FROM question
   WHERE contains(answertext, '{pric}', 1) > 0

;
```

This query returns nothing. But using {pricing} will return the correct result.

And suggestion why this is happening would be great!

Edit: just wanted to add that using stemming does not work for me because the user wants to differentiate between "report" and "reporting" and they want the matching substring to be highlighted which can be done if I can find the substring among the returned results.

Edit 2: I have my guess, that oracle tokenizes each word using word boundary of some sort in the index, and thus without any wildcards it looks for a token that equals = 'pric' and therefore does not find it (because there is a token 'pricing'). So, if that guess is correct I would love if someone can chime in for how I can make the query above work with the example entry while still maintaining whitespace so if type 'pricing options' it should return but if i type 'many options' it should not...

Answer (score 2):

`CONTAINS` operator supports [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cqoper.htm#i998461) and fuzzy text search. Try:

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE contains(answertext, '{pric%}', 1) > 0;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE contains(answertext, 'fuzzy({pric})', 1) > 0;
```

But with `fuzzy` `"prize"` will also match your search criteria.

To highlight found substrings you can use [`CTX_DOC.MARKUP`](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/ctx_doc_markup.php).